# How to check if there is an object already on the excel sheet, and if there isnt then insert the file?

Tags: vba, excel

This block of code opens the select file window and then includes the file onto the sheet. the problem is that there is no limit to how many times you can do that.  How can i perform a check and stop it from includeding more than one files?

```
Public Sub insertFile()

'Select the cell in which you want to place the attachment
Range("F92").Select

'Get file path
fpath = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files,*.*", Title:="Select file")
If LCase(fpath) = "false" Then Exit Sub

'Insert file
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add _
Filename:=fpath, _
Link:=False, _
DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
IconFileName:="excel.exe", _
IconIndex:=0, _
IconLabel:=extractFileName(fpath)

End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function extractFileName(filePath)

    For i = Len(filePath) To 1 Step -1
        If Mid(filePath, i, 1) = "\" Then
        extractFileName = Mid(filePath, i + 1, Len(filePath) - i + 1)
        Exit Function
        End If
Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a simple

```
If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Count > 0 Then Exit Sub
```

at the start of your `sub`?